# Getting trouble with jQuery dialog box:Close function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I need to check whether user is logged-in or not in different cases like `while clicked on contact button` and `while tries to vote up/down` and `while tries to write comment on a post`.In all these cases if user already logged-in then I'm allowing to do necessary actions but if not logged-in then I need to show 'login form as dialog box'.

I'm using common `login dialog box` for cases,there is no issues with implementing the functionality as mentioned above but the issue is,

1.suppose if user click's on contact button and he his not logged-in then I'm showing `login form dialog box`,here if user close's the `login dialog box` instead of submitting his details to login. If he his successfully logged-in then I need to show `contact form dialog box`.

2.After that if he click's on `vote up button` then after successful login-in then instead of `vote number raising,contact form dialog box` is opening due point 1 action by user.

I'm hiding the `dialog box` in `close function` of the `dialog box` as follows

```
    $(selector).dialog({
        closeOnEscape: false,
        title:title,
        modal: true,
        close:function()
        {
        $(this).dialog('destroy').hide();
        }
        });
```

If I use multiple `login forms` then code is getting redundant, and tried something like this also but not worked

```
    $(selector).dialog({
        closeOnEscape: false,
        title:title,
        modal: true,
        open:function()
        {
          $(this).attr('id','unique-id');
        }, 
        close:function()
        {
        $(this).dialog('destroy').hide();
        }
        });
```

Comment: Your steps are not clear. What is step 1 ?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal: In step 1,user just close's the `login form dialog box`  after opening when clicked on `contact button`. Because of this action after successful login `when tries to vote up`,`contact dialog box is opening`.

Comment: I guess then you should check the condition due to which you are opening the dialogue.After successful login are you resetting that value to false?

Comment: The whole problem is due to as I'm hiding the `login dialog box` instead of removing,but if I remove then its not poping up next time.

Comment: $(this).dialog("close"); use this on close. This will close the dialogue but make it available the next time if required. This does not destruct it.